# WCF in memory / assembly binding

Tags: .net, wcf, process, in-memory, .net-assembly

Are there any options on using WCF to do in memory calls to assemblies?
Currently we deploy multiple services over basicHttp binding on different servers, for a single machine installation it would be enough to do an in memory call to the service. Is there any binding I can use without having to host the services locally (so not with named pipes) but in-process?

The endpoint location could be than something like this for example:

```
assembly://MyCoolService.dll
```

Comment: What would MyCoolService.dll contain, to make this idea mean anything? And what do you mean by "without having to host the services locally". If you don't need any of the services provided by the WCF channel stack runtime, you can instantiate your service class and call its operation methods directly. If the service does depend on WCF runtime services, you can't avoid the need to provide a ServiceHost.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such build-in binding. NetNamedPipe is usually used for that. The only option is to check [NullTransport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/NullTransportForWCF.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

no this is not possible, net.pipe binding is the closest you can get (and the with the best performance).